# How do I use a simple solution for adding salts for water treatment?

Tags: water

I am thinking of dissolving a 1:1 salt to distilled water solution of a weight/volume that I can measure easier,  then adding just the needed amount of the solution to my mash according to my water profile. I would store the rest of the solution for brewing batches later on.

The trouble has been measuring in such small quantities for 5 gallons brews. I hope to simplify the process without sacrificing precision.

My dilemma is in how much of the solution I would need to calculate to add to the mash/sparge. For example, if a profile calls for 1 gram of a salt and my solution is equal grams to milliliters, would I add 2 milliliters of solution for the 1 gram?  The way I see it is 1 milliliter would be 50% salt and 50% water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a 1g:1mL solution, then you still need to be *as* precise, you've just changed the measure from grams to milliliters (not millimeters ;). This might still be a useful change, though; sometimes its easier to measure volume than weight.

Instead, make a 1g:10mL solution. Now, assuming you can accurately measure 1mL of the solution, you can measure out 0.1g of the salt. A 1g:100mL solution would let you be uselessly precise! :)

Start with 1g of salt, then add enough water to *end up* at 100mL of solution.  You might have added 99.5mL, but you now have 1g of salt distributed in now 100mL of solution.

It bears pointing out you can get 0.1g-accurate digital scales for $10 and 0.01g-accurate scales for $20. My usual salt additions for 10gl batches are 2.x-6.x-8.x grams, so a 0.1g-accurate scale is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I wasn't paying attention to spell check. I am aware of the scales but I am avoiding equipment purchases for a little while. If I can't get this to work then I will inevitably have to get one. My current scale only goes down to 1g. I was thinking more on the lines of 50g for 100ml solution.

Comment: You could do a 1:2 solution, sure. My point is more that the higher the ratio, the easier it is to achieve your goal of measuring smaller quantities.  At 50g:100mL, if you need eg. 0.5 g of salt, you'll need to measure out 1mL. If you can accurately measure 1mL, then fine.  At 1g:100mL, 0.5g is 50mL, a much easier amount to measure, and more forgiving of lower precision.

Comment: I like the idea you suggested of a larger water to salt ratio for easier calculations. I was originally looking to see if this idea was even feasible. I was thinking (not being overly knowledgeable in chemistry) that somehow mass might decrease when desolving. Now I see that it not only is feasible,  it could be workable. Thanks.